# Dxhtml gantt chart using Angular_2

Tags: javascript, angular, nodes

I am working on dxhtml gant chart using angular 2.Below is the output which I am getting [output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb7yB.png)

```
gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskAdd", function(id,item){ 
    //any custom logic here return true; 
}); //This is my task.ts file content export class Task 
{ id: number; start_date: string; text: string; progress: number; duration: number; parent: number; }
```

Here I want to alert or abort the operation when user is trying to load the same task description ,but I am not getting how to proceed with It.
[code for task inserting updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHzc4.png)

Comment: Don't only image please post your code

Comment: https://github.com/alexangular1/ganttchart/blob/master/README.md   I am refrring this official doc but I am not getting any clue about adding unique task description

Comment: gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskAdd", function(id,item){
    //any custom logic here
    return true;
});      This is my task.ts file content export class Task {
 id: number;
 start_date: string;
 text: string;
 progress: number;
 duration: number;
 parent: number;
}  I just want to know now that how can we proceed now so that we can compare the text